# Private inner class

Tags: class, methods, call, private

```java
package package1;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("Hi banda");     
        Test n = new Test();
        Test1 t = n.new Test1();
        t.show();
        // Test1 t1 = n.Test1.show();
    }

    private class Test1{
         int l = 10;
         void show() {
            System.out.println("inner class" + l);
        }       
    }

}
```

How can I see `show()` output

Comment: What do you mean? I can see the output here...

Comment: your code is OK, What do you want?